# wrong path displayed for stored files

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel image intervention.I have some files stored in my Storage folder within a path of **/storage/app/public/images**.When I am trying to generate the path of the files by

```
$path=Storage::disk('local')->url('screenshot1.jpg');
```

and doing dd($path),its giving me the path like,

> "/storage/screenshot1.jpg"

and I want a path,

> "/storage/app/public/images/screenshot1.jpg"

I also made some changes in my filesystem.php inorder to get the required path,

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
        'region' => 'your-region',
        'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    ],

],
```

but still does not work..

Answer (score 0):

the path is returned correctly but, but to get the content in url you need to copy it from storage to publick folder in your path, othwerise you should return is as base64 to the client. because the storage is not directly accessible from public.

You need to make symlink with storage/app/public/images
if the folder images is not create in public then create it before you do symlink

```
ln -s storage/app/public/images public/images
```

Comment: i have these images stored in the public folder as well but still it returns the same path,do i have to make changes to this filesystem.php file

Comment: do symlink for storage/app/public/images to public/images

Comment: This is what my gitbash returns,
$ ln -s storage/app/public/images public/images
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'public/images': No such file or directory

Comment: do mkdir at public/images , this says thay the folder directory images in public folder doesnt exist, then do symbolic